# Existe alguma maneira de atribuir valores a um vetor mais rapidamente?

Tags: c, array

Por exemplo, tenho a declaração do seguinte vetor:

```
float vet[3] = {1, 1, 1};
```

Teria como mudar todos valores do mesmo de uma só vez, sem ter que mudar um por um elemento ou criar um novo vetor e atribuir a ele:

```
vet[0] = -1;
vet[1] = 0;
vet[2] = 1;
```

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
vet = {-1, 0, 1};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De forma direta não tem não. Poderia criar uma função onde passa os parâmetros e ela atribui cada elemento. Mas isso é o oposto de ser mais rápido, no máximo fica mais curto.

Isso de forma geral vai contra a filosofia básica do C, embora nada impede de ser usado se for o mais adequado pontualmente.

Comment: No meu caso isso é o mais adequado, pois tenho que trocar o valor do vetor dezenas ou centenas de vezes. Criei a função `void createVector(float *vet, float e1, float e2, float e3) {
  vet[0] = e1;
  vet[1] = e2;
  vet[2] = e3;
}`

Comment: Aí faz sentido, embora a sintaxe não deveria ser essa.

Comment: Deveria ser como? Sem o ponteiro? Se for isso eu tirei, estava fazendo uns testes aqui daí esqueci de mudar pra `float vet[3]` kk

Comment: Isso mesmo. tem outras formas de formas de fazer, mas se essa te atende, ela é adequada.